# How to add a .lib file to a project in a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2019, lib

I have a Visual Studio 2019 Solution with two projects.  One project builds a .lib file and I need the other project which builds an .exe file to link to the .lib file.  How do I make the settings of the project which produces the .exe file link to the lib file and recognize the path to it?

When I google for a solution to this, I get from "how to link a project to a lib file in a project":

"under Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > MCU GCC Linker > Libraries add the . a library name and the path to that file."

But when I do this, I can not find "C/C++ Build " in the dialog box that pops up.